# How to use image without making .exe heavier c#

Tags: c#, image, winforms

How to **use image without making .exe file heavier in c# windows application**.

One way is **keeping the file in debug folder and reading it at runtime** but i **dont want the user to see any images in the debug folder**.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure making the exe bigger is a bad thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store images in a separate Class Library and then reference it in your application.

Users wouldn't be able to see the image files this way, instead they would be stored as a dll file in your debug folder.

**Edit:**

I have recorded the actions required to achieve this setup, check out this link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8i794GmZ_aI

Comment: sounds good but how to do so? i mean i know how to create class libraries but how to store images and use in another project?

Comment: problem with your code is that i can get string with it but how to get image with it? i mean your code cannot get my image? please try it and edit the solution.

Comment: @Agent_Spock can you detail why this would be better?  You've now have more space used by binaries rather than having the image in the original binaries, plus more load time finding and loading the extra class library.

Comment: as images would not change again and again just had to transfer the   lighter exe to do the work